# How can I get PhpStorm to go to the right declaration

Tags: php, phpstorm, code-completion, code-hinting

I have the following snippet of code.

```
abstract class MrParent {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->var = 'a';
  }
}

class MrChild extends MrParent {
  public function hello() {
    echo 'Hello';
  }
}

$MrGuy = new MrChild();
```

Now, in PhpStorm, when I middle-click ("Go To Declaration") on the last line of the "MrChild" class, the cursor jumps up to the "__construct" line. I was expecting it to go to the "class MrChild extends MrParent" line.

In a single document, this is OK, but in a setup where it's one class per file, this is quite annoying because it means the IDE is constantly showing me the class I don't want.

I know that if I added the following code to the "MrChild" class, I'd get what I want, but that seems like I shouldn't be fixing what I consider to be an IDE bug by adding extra code.

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: so this is a question about your IDE phpStorm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing [WI-4880](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-4880) issue. Feel free to watch/vote.